# How to specify HTML doctype in Oracle SQL*Plus HTML report?

Tags: html, oracle, report, sqlplus

I'm producing an HTML report from a query using:

> ```
> set markup html on table "WIDTH='100%' BORDER='1'
> cellpadding='2px' cellspacing='0px'";
> ```

Is there a way of including a doctype declaration such as:

> ```
> <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
>  "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
> ```

I've searched but I can't see an obvious way of doing this.

**UPDATE:** Simply adding a prompt with a doctype produces the following (which produces another validation error!):

> ```
> <html>
>     <head>
>         <META HTTP-EQUIV="Content-Type" CONTENT="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
>         <style type="text/css">pre{background-color:white;font-family:"Courier New";font-size:16;color:black;}</style>
>     </head>
> <body>
>     <pre>
>         <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
> ```

Comment: DOCTYPE declarations need to be at the beginning of the file. They are above / outside the <html> element. You can view the source of this webpage and see.

Comment: Yeah I know DOCTYPEs need to be at the start of the file. Any idea about how to do it? ;)

Comment: put the PROMPT statement BEFORE the set markup html on statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you're executing from the command line something like this:

```
SQLPLUS -S -M "HTML ON" user/password@yourDB @yourQuery.sql > output.html
```

What you can do is add some shell scripting to concatenate the DOCTYPE and the report. Let's assume the doctype is being put in a file DOCTYPE.TXT. You don't specify an environment, but let's try... Windows. Then we would have

```
SQLPLUS -S -M "HTML ON" user/password@yourDB @yourQuery.sql > intermediate.html
COPY DOCTYPE.TXT+intermediate.html output.html
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not simply put a

```
prompt <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
     "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
```

in your script, BEFORE the `set markup html on` statement?